# Pass value of an object from DAO to servlet in 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, servlets

I would like to print the values of an object from DAO to servlet.

DAO:

```
public static List getFree(String svLectID,String ExLectID) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        currentCon = JavaConnectionDB.getConnection() ;
        PreparedStatement ps1 = currentCon.prepareStatement("SELECT *\n" +
                                                            "FROM   (\n" +
                                                            "        SELECT      e1.FreeID,\n" +
                                                            "                    e1.lecturerID SVID,\n" +
                                                            "                    e1.availableID SVavail,\n" +
                                                            "                    e1.freedate AS SVFree,\n" +
                                                            "                    e2.lecturerID AS Examiner, \n" +
                                                            "                    e2.freedate EXFree,\n" +
                                                            "                    s.studentID,\n" +
                                                            "                    s.studentName,\n" +
                                                            "                    s.lecturerID AS lectID,\n" +
                                                            "                    sv.lecturerID AS SVlecturerID,\n" +
                                                            "                    sv.lecturerFullname AS SVlecturerName,\n" +
                                                            "                    ex.lecturerID AS EXlecturerID,\n" +
                                                            "                    ex.lecturerFullname AS EXlecturerName,\n" +
                                                            "                    v.availableID availID,\n" +
                                                            "                    v.availableDay,\n" +
                                                            "                    v.availableStart,\n" +
                                                            "                    v.availableEnd,\n" +
                                                            "                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY e1.lecturerID \n" +
                                                            "                                       ORDER BY dbms_random.random) AS rn\n" +
                                                            "        FROM        free e1 \n" +
                                                            "        INNER JOIN  free e2 \n" +
                                                            "                ON  e1.availableID = e2.availableID\n" +
                                                            "        INNER JOIN  student s\n" +
                                                            "                ON  s.lecturerID = e1.lecturerID\n" +
                                                            "        INNER JOIN  lecturer sv\n" +
                                                            "                ON  sv.lecturerID = e1.lecturerID\n" +
                                                            "        INNER JOIN  lecturer ex\n" +
                                                            "                ON  ex.lecturerID = e2.lecturerID\n" +
                                                            "        INNER JOIN  availability v\n" +
                                                            "                ON  v.availableID = e2.availableID\n" +
                                                            "                \n" +
                                                            "      \n" +
                                                            "        WHERE       e1.lecturerID = ? \n" +
                                                            "               AND  e2.lecturerID = ? \n" +
                                                            "               ORDER BY e2.availableID asc\n" +
                                                            "              \n" +
                                                            "        )\n" +
                                                            "WHERE rn <=5") ;
        ps1.setString(1, svLectID) ;
        ps1.setString(2, ExLectID);
        List list = new ArrayList() ;
        ResultSet rs1 = ps1.executeQuery() ;
        while(rs1.next())
        {
            Object[] obj = new Object[17] ;
            obj[0] = rs1.getString(1) ;
            obj[1] = rs1.getString(2);
            obj[2] = rs1.getInt(3);
            obj[3] = rs1.getDate(4);
            obj[4] = rs1.getString(5);
            obj[5] = rs1.getDate(6);
            obj[6] = rs1.getString(7);
            obj[7] = rs1.getString(8);
            obj[8] = rs1.getString(9);
            obj[9] = rs1.getString(10);
            obj[10] = rs1.getString(11);
            obj[11] = rs1.getString(12);
            obj[12] = rs1.getString(13);
            obj[13] = rs1.getInt(14);
            obj[14] = rs1.getString(15);
            obj[15] = rs1.getDate(16);
            obj[16] = rs1.getDate(17);
            list.add(obj) ;
            System.out.println("zabir "+rs1.getString(8));
        }
        return list ;
    }
```

As you can see these values are stored in an object into a list. I retrieve these values to servlet.

SERVLET:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, java.io.IOException {

         currentCon = JavaConnectionDB.getConnection();


         // Set response content type
         response.setContentType("text/html");
         PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
         ServletContext context=getServletContext(); 

         String[] studentID = request.getParameterValues("studentID");
         String[] supervisorID =  request.getParameterValues("supervisorID"); 
         String[] examinerID = request.getParameterValues("examinerID");


        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");


         try{ 
             out.println("<br><center><table><tr>"
                                    + "<th>Student Name</th>"
                                    + "<th>Project Title</th>"
                                    + "<th>Supervisor Name</th>"
                                    + "<th>Examiner Name</th>"
                                    + "<th>Start</th>"
                                    + "<th>End</th>"
                                    + "<th>Date</th>"
                                    + "</tr>");


                          for (int i=0 ; i<studentID.length ; i++){

                                FreeBean free = new FreeBean();
                                PresentationBean present = new PresentationBean();
                                StudentBean student = new StudentBean();
                                List list = new ArrayList() ;

                                int SVavailableID = free.getAvailableID();
                                int EXavailableID = free.getAvailableID();


                                list =  GenerateScheduleDAO.getFree(supervisorID[i],examinerID[i]);

                                System.out.println(list.get(0)); //DEBUGGED HERE 
                                System.out.println(list); //DEBUGGED HERE


                               out.println("<tr>");
                               out.println("<tr>");
                               out.println("<td>"+ studentID[i]+"</td>");
                               out.println("<td> Hello </td>");
                               out.println("<td>"+ supervisorID[i] +"</td>");
                               out.println("<td>"+ examinerID[i] +"</td>");
                               out.println("<td>"+ SVavailableID+"</td>");
                               out.println("<td>"+ EXavailableID+"</td>");
                               out.println("<td>"+ EXFreeDate+"</td>");
                               out.println("</tr>");


                            }//student loop
                            out.println("</center></table><br><br>");

         out.println("</body>");
         out.println("</html>");            
         }// first try
         catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace() ;
                }//first catch

     }//throws method
```

I tried to get the value using SOP first like this:

```
 System.out.println(list.get(0)); //DEBUGGED HERE 
 System.out.println(list); //DEBUGGED HERE
```

First SOP produce : `[Ljava.lang.Object;@13432ad`
Second SOP produce : `[[Ljava.lang.Object;@1dd079f,`

My first assumption was `get(0)` wil give me `FreeID` value. As declared in DAO.
So how can i get the value if using `get(0)` is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `freeId` should be in the first position of each array present in the `list` returned by the method `getFree`.

To get the `freeId` of the first element of the `list` you should do something like:

```
System.out.println((Object[]) list.get(0))[0]);
```

For the freeId of the second element of the list:

```
System.out.println((Object[]) list.get(1))[0]);
```

and so on.

It will be more readable doing something like that:

```
Object[] firstObjectAsArray = (Object[]) list.get(0);
System.out.println(firstObjectAsArray[0]);

Object[] secondObjectAsArray = (Object[]) list.get(1);
System.out.println(secondObjectAsArray[0]);
```

---

To print the `freeId` of all elements of the `list`

```
for (Object objectAsArray : list) {
    System.out.println(((Object[]) objectAsArray)[0]);
}
```

---

Note: looking at your code there is a not necessary creation of an empty list. The code:

```
List list = new ArrayList() ;   // Not necessary
int SVavailableID = free.getAvailableID();
int EXavailableID = free.getAvailableID();
list =  GenerateScheduleDAO.getFree(supervisorID[i],examinerID[i]);
```

can be optimized as follow:

```
int SVavailableID = free.getAvailableID();
int EXavailableID = free.getAvailableID();
List list =  GenerateScheduleDAO.getFree(supervisorID[i],examinerID[i]);
```

---

Note: using generics you don't need the cast. To do that replace the definition of the list

```
List list = new ArrayList();
```

with

```
List<Object[]> list = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
```

Comment: I honestly have tried  for using `list.get(1)[0]` before. But I am still getting error. The error is `array required, but Object found`

Comment: Yes because you need to define the list with generics or you need an explicit cast

Comment: @user6308605 I added the cast in the code. But it is better to define the list as List<Object[]> instead of only List. I added the code at the end of the answer

Comment: Is it okay if i cast like this `List<Object[]> list =  GenerateScheduleDAO.getFree(supervisorID[i],examinerID[i]);` which one is better?

Comment: You can, but the cast need to be as follow: `List<Object[]> list = (List<Object[]) GenerateScheduleDAO.getFree(supervisorID[i],examinerID[i]);`

Comment: (List<Object[]>) I think you missed `>` :) Thank you very much for your help

Comment: @user6308605 Right sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Your `list` contains **arrays** of Object, so you have to call the relevant indexes of the array.

You could debug the full list like this

```
// iterate over the list
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

            Object[] array = (Object[])(list.get(i));

            // iterate over the Object array
            for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {

                System.out.println(array[j]);

            }

}
```

Comment: Just add the code below this `list =  GenerateScheduleDAO.getFree(supervisorID[i],examinerID[i]);` right?

Comment: Yes it is the exact same list that you used in your code.

Comment: I added the cast to Object array. However, as @Davide Lorenzo MARINO said, declaring your lists everywhere as `List<Object[]>` will avoid the need for casting

Comment: Thank you very much for the loops haha. Thank you thank you :)